# aspx, response.write, image and link referencing

Tags: asp.net

I've spent a while trying to find out whether what I want is possible.

I have 3 websites on different domains. Two are in English, one in French. We have one page in english, one in french which are identical apart from the text. These pages and relevant images (we'll call common content) are stored on a **separate** domain (reasons beyond my control) and use response-writefile to insert the content into the two english pages.

Got all that working fine. However, the images in these common pages have a path relative to domain on which they are stored, which means when the pages are written into the main pages, the images dont show. I understand why and can get around it by putting in the full path of the image.

I would prefer not to go through every single page changing the image path, is there any way of the server knowing or being told that the image is relative to the common content and not the rendered page?

I wouldn't have thought so, but it would save my day if there was!

**Further explanation:**

Relative path of image:

`abc.png`

Path of common content file:

`http://domain1.com/CommonContent/123.html`

Code in final pages (domain2.com/english.html):

`<% Response.WriteFile("/CommonContent/123.html"); %>`

Rendered path of image (what I don't want):

`http://domain2.com/abd.png`

Ideal path of image in rendered page: ie, what I want to happen:

`http://domain1.com/CommonContent/abd.png`

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use WebClient class to get the page content

```
String URI = "http://domain1.com/CommonContent/123.html";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(URI);
String request = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

then you perform a string replace, here I'm not sure what can match, maybe something like this can match:

```
request.Replace("<src=", "<src=http://domain1.com/CommonContent/")
```

then you render this string to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can make [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) having the path for each domain on each application, and then maybe add a function that will be in charge of writing the full path of the pictures. Also you can make an [HTTP Module](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996) to address this issue as well as a [Generic Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) that will receive all requests for images and load them from different domains/applications.

Good luck!